# Determining when to stop a possibly infinite iteration?

Tags: iteration

As a beginner programmer, a common problem I encounter is when to stop an iteration. For example, if I were to program a function to determine if an integer was [happy](https://prime-numbers.info/article/happy-primes) or not (by brute-force ), when would I stop? Another example, concerning something like the [Mandelbrot set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set), how would I know to stop an iteration and firmly say that a number diverges or converges? Does it depend on the problem you're dealing with, or is there a method to do things like this?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: Huh, I've heard of this problem before but I didn't know it had anything to do with this issue I've been having.

Comment: However, from the wiki article, it claims that the problem is undecidable over Turing machines. Does this mean that there is no way to know when to stop?

Comment: I think it depends on the problem itself as well. 
For example, for `happy prime` numbers, you can stop if you identify a loop in your code. If you don't you will have to keep going until the sums converge to 1 or you identify a loop (both being a halting condition).
Halting problems are theoretically impossible to solve, so Yes, you can not determine if or not stop looping.

Comment: Using the loop identification technique seems like a good method. I guess I must know the end behaviors of input numbers in order to be able to efficiently halt an iteration. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brute-force method you have to find your base case to terminate your program as in case of recursion. For Happy Prime number the base case is finding loop in your iteration.

**Code**

```
# sum of square of digit of n 
def numSquareSum(n): 
    squareSum = 0 
    while(n): 
        squareSum += (n % 10) * (n % 10) 
        n = int(n / 10) 
    return squareSum


#method return true if n is Happy Number 
def isHappyNumber(n): 
    li = [] 
    while (1):
        n = numSquareSum(n) 
        if (n == 1): 
            return True 
        if (n in li): 
            return False 
        li.append(n) 
# Main Code 
n = 7; 
if (isHappyNumber(n)): 
    print(n , "is a Happy number")
else: 
    print(n , "is not a Happy number")
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are describing is the Halting Problem. The main takeaway to Halting Problem is that computers cannot solve every problem. One of which being detecting generic infinite loops. It depends on the specific problem you are trying to solve, whether there is a solution to detecting infinite loops.

If you have anymore questions please refer to [Wiki on the Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

Answer (score 1):

In NASA's [The Power of 10: Rules for Developing Safety-Critical Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_of_10:_Rules_for_Developing_Safety-Critical_Code) there is a rule "All loops must have fixed bounds. This prevents runaway code."

In this trivial example this would be:

```
# sum of square of digit of n 
def numSquareSum(n): 
    count = 0
    squareSum = 0 
    while(n): 
        squareSum += (n % 10) * (n % 10) 
        n = int(n / 10) 
        count += 1
        if count > 100000000:
            raise Exception('loop bound exceeded')
    return squareSum
```